# Css кроссбраузерная проблема

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, кроссбраузерность

Есть фрагмент разметки:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <p>Наполнение</p>
</div>
```

И соответсвующий фрагмент стиля:

```
.item img {
    content: url(../img/star.png);
    width: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

В целом это работает корректно, но не во всех брузерах. А точнее не отображается изображение. В Chrome всё работает, но при просмотре в Лисе или в Edge,изображение не отображается, буд-то его просто нету. В отладке всё на месте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предположил, что нужно явно задать и высоту, но в итоге просто увеличивается пустое пространство.
Как это можно поправить?

P.S. Используется Bootstarp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Удивительно, что где-то работает. http://htmlbook.ru/css/content
Обратите внимание на фразу "применяется к псевдоэлементам :before и :after"

Comment: Ну тогда понятно, тогда вопрос в том, каким образом правильно задавать значение `src`? Предположу что с помощью такого паттерна: `background: url(../img/star.png); background-size: 100%;`, или есть более специализированное свойство?

Comment: Да, можно background или background-image использовать. Только поменяйте img в коде на div. Относительно background-size я был предложил дать ему не 100%, а cover.